# Lançar Exception no onCreate de uma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento e refatoração de algumas `Activity's` que tem comportamentos similares em nossos projetos, então para evitar repetições de códigos, para funcionalidades comuns, criei algumas `Activity's` base, que são herdadas pelas outras Activity's.

Meu problema é o seguinte, como o que estou criando é `class` base (*library*), que pode ser utilizada por varias outras, necessito garantir de que quem for utiliza-la irá utiliza-la da forma correta. Assim sendo, gostaria de verificar inconformidades nos parâmetros da `class` base e lançar uma `Exception` caso haja inconformidades, para que estes erros sejam capturados ainda na fase de desenvolvimento e testes.

Isso não parece ser possível, acompanhem a seguir o que gostaria de fazer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    userHelper = new UserHelper(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.container_for_fragment);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
        }else{
            // essa linha não compila: "Unhandled exception type Exception"
            throw new Exception("mFragment, deve ser setado antes da chamada do onCreate() da class base \"ListAbstractActivity\"");
        }
    }
}
```

**Duvidas**

1. Há alguma forma de fazer algo nesse sentido?
2. O que estou tentando fazer é certo?
3. Há alguma alternativa plausível para está situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso do erro *"Unhandled exception type Exception"* que você mencionou, esse código não irá compilar porque `Exception` é uma *checked exception*, isto é, o método que a lança é obrigado a declarar que pode lançá-la:

```
onCreate(...) throws Exception {
```

Como o compilador provavelmente não irá deixar você declarar isso (pois iria alterar a assinatura do método `onCreate`), lance em vez disso uma `RuntimeException` ou uma de suas subclasses que você considere mais apropriada.

Comment: OMG, @Piovezan, caramba não utilizo `Exceptions` para controle de fluxo, então, não tenho muito conhecimento sobre as mesmas. Então há isso _"checked exception"_.  Sendo assim `Exception` e seus descendentes, são para exceções que eu espero e quero trata-las, e `RuntimeException` e seus descendentes para exceções que devem quebrar realmente a aplicação. Certo? Poderia explicar brevemente a diferença entre as duas?

Comment: Só para complementar, implementei da forma que você citou e aparentemente funciona corretamente. +1, e se tudo der certo já já marco como resposta. E obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: A explicação é basicamente como você falou. Uma _checked exception_ precisa ser tratada ou declarada na assinatura do método. São basicamente para situações "recuperáveis", enquanto que as _runtime_ são para erros de programação. Mas há um pouco mais a falar sobre exceções que deixariam a explicação mais longa. Veja por exemplo [esta pergunta no SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Comment: Então, por se tratar de um assunto um pouco amplo, e fora do escopo dessa questão, vou verificar se já há, e eventualmente criar uma nova pergunta aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Postei [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55624/exception-vs-runtimeexception-quando-utilizar-uma-ou-outra) a respeito de `Exception` vs `RuntimeException`