# Exception vs RuntimeException, quando utilizar um ou outro?

Tags: java, android, exceção

Estava com [essa dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55608/lan%C3%A7ar-exception-no-oncreate-de-uma-activity), e ao ser esclarecido da mesma me surgiu outra, que gostaria que fosse melhor esclarecida.

- Qual a diferença entre `Exception` e `RuntimeException`?
- Quando utilizar `Exception` ou `RuntimeException`?

> Se possível um exemplo didático do uso de `Exception` e `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) deve ser usada quando a exceção **pode** ser prevenida. Use ela, indiretamente, quando quer sinalizar para o programador usuário do seu código que ele **pode** tentar resolver o problema quando esta exceção for lançada. Por causa disto ela é considerada uma exceção não checada.

Elas são muito usadas em erros de programação que só podem ser verificados em tempo de execução, por isto não é obrigado capturar. Erro de programação deve deixar a aplicação quebrar. Eles só ocorrem porque não foram prevenidos antes de acontecer, por isto são chamados erros de programação. Uma verificação antes do erro ocorrer resolverá o problema. Exemplos de erros deste tipo são `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` e `NullPointerException`.

Nada impede de você criar suas próprias derivadas desta classe. Você só não deve fazer isto porque não quer ter o trabalho de capturar depois. A filosofia do Java é que sempre que for possível fazer algo com o problema, uma exceção deve ser capturada, então este tipo de exceção deve ser evitada tanto quanto possível. O que não quer dizer que qualquer exceção deve ser capturada. Mesmo as exceções checadas muitas vezes o melhor é delegar para outro método. E as não checadas só devem ser capturadas se naquele contexto você consegue fazer algo para se recuperar do erro, mesmo que seja apresentar uma mensagem personalizada.

Para erros que **devem** ser prevenidos usa-se a `Exception` que é mais genérica e envolve qualquer exceção, inclusive ela pode ser uma `RuntimeException` já que todas as exceções devem ser derivadas de [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). Também é usada indiretamente. Ela é considerada um exceção checada. Ou seja, todas as exceções que não são `RuntimeException` são checadas. Exemplos são todas derivadas e a própria `IOException` ou `DataFormatException`. Estas exceções ocorrem em situação que o programador não costuma poder controlar, depende do uso da aplicação e talvez só o usuário dela é que pode fazer alguma coisa.

Quando uma exceção checada é usada, o código deve capturá-la ou usar [`throws`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101) (há exemplos de uso e mais informações nessa pergunta) no método para delegar sua captura. As exceções de *runtime* não precisam fazer isto, como o próprio nome indica elas não devem ser consideradas pelo compilador. Claro que cabe ao programador analisar a situação e decidir se aquele caso deve usar uma exceção checada ou não, quando é opcional. Há casos que mesmo um erro de *runtime* deveria ser obrigado a ter algum tratamento quando o seu fluxo depende daquilo correto e algo pode ser melhor tratado.

É importante salientar que o uso destas classes é indireto porque o ideal é lançar exceções derivadas delas e não elas mesmas que são muito genéricas e idealmente até deveriam ser abstratas. Sempre deve-se lançar as [exceções mais específicas possíveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101).

[Documentação de exceções](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

#### Hierarquia Java Exception

[image: Hierarquia Java Exception]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, sua resposta me ajudou a compreender um pouco melhor, o que é, e quando usar cada uma. +1

Answer (score 6):

Você pediu exemplos didáticos. Os que tenho são os que aprendi com a experiência.

No caso das *checked exceptions* vejo que é comum bibliotecas de manipulação de dados lançarem exceções relacionadas a I/O e a *parsing* (interpretação) de dados.

A biblioteca "clássica" de I/O do Java por exemplo lança `IOException`, `FileNotFoundException` e `EOFException`, para citar as mais comuns.

Bibliotecas de *networking* e comunicação HTTP, por também realizarem I/O, lançam no mínimo `IOException`.

Um parser de JSON como o do *json.org* que vem junto com o Android pode lançar uma `JSONException` relacionada à leitura de um dado a partir de uma string JSON, já o Gson do Google pode lançar uma `JsonSyntaxException`.

Enfim, são situações em que a biblioteca em si não está preparada para lidar com o erro e opta por repassá-lo para um nível mais alto da pilha de chamadas ou *call stack*. Ela faz isso declarando que essas exceções, se ocorrerem, precisarão ser tratadas por quem faz uso daquela API. Ela expõe essa possibilidade na própria API, que está declarando a possibilidade de ocorrer aquela exceção checada (ou talvez possamos chamá-la de "verificável").

Essa é uma das vantagens de se trabalhar com exceções: assim como você pode tratá-las no ponto em que ocorrem, você pode também delegar esse tratamento para um nível que esteja mais capacitado para tratar, ou "se recuperar", do erro ocorrido.

Ao declarar isso na forma de uma *checked exception*, você está sinalizando o código "usuário" que aquele erro merece atenção e provavelmente algum tipo de tratamento. E costuma ser tipicamente um erro "recuperável": seu aplicativo pode se preparar antecipadamente para um JSON malformado, um arquivo não encontrado ou uma interrupção na comunicação em rede. São erros, digamos, previsíveis.

É diferente de uma *runtime exception* no sentido de que a *runtime* representa tipicamente um erro no funcionamento do código em si, um erro que você pega durante a execução e precisa corrigir o código e evitar que aconteça, como falou o @Maniero. Você precisa "blindar" seu código contra ela depois de descobrir que ela ocorre.

Para citar os cenários que mais usava na época que respondi essa pergunta, pode ser o caso de um parâmetro que não deveria nunca ser passado como `null`, caso contrário irá lançar uma `IllegalArgumentException` ou uma `NullPointerException`, ou então um estado que teoricamente não deveria acontecer sob pena de lançar uma `IllegalStateException` (exemplo: um método que só deve ser chamado pela thread de UI do Android e você involuntariamente chama a partir de uma thread secundária).

Quando meu código lança uma dessas exceções, eu admito que não espero que aconteçam, mas às vezes acontecem e eu sei que se trata de um defeito no código.

Eu confesso que já tratei `IOException` dentro de uma biblioteca minha de chamada a *web services* em vez de delegar para o código usuário. Eu "engolia" a exceção (quando muito logava) e retornava `null` na minha resposta. Foi uma péssima decisão de design. Meu código usuário não sabia quando vinha um `null` a partir de uma requisição bem-sucedida ou quando vinha a partir de um erro de I/O, e são duas situações diferentes que exigem tratamento diferente. Não era a minha biblioteca que precisava tratar exceções de I/O e sim o código que fazia uso dela.

Já em um código mais recente em que fazia uso do Apache HTTP Client eu declarei o seguinte:

```
private HttpResponse executarRequisicaoSincrona(DataTransferRequest requisicao)
throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
```

Veja como esse método delega para outro nível duas *checked exceptions*, uma de I/O específica (que é a de *encoding* não suportado) e uma de I/O mais genérica.

As duas são passíveis de ocorrer durante uma requisição HTTP em situações distintas e eu achei por bem não tratá-las no mesmo nível em que são lançadas e sim passá-las para a frente, pois nesse momento meu código não sabe ainda o que fazer com elas.

Se soubesse, poderia tratá-las dentro do próprio método `executarRequisicaoSincrona` em vez de declará-las, mas não é esse o caso no meu código.

Espero que com essas experiências você possa ter uma noção mais precisa de quando usar ou lançar exceções dos dois tipos, *checked* e *unchecked*.

[Este *link*](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html) explica muito bem a diferença entre as duas e quando usar uma ou outra (na verdade ele explica quais são as melhores práticas sobre tratamento de exceções no Java). Eu o recomendo fortemente.

Comment: Piovezan, muito boas suas analogias a cenários reais, de bibliotecas populares, posteriormente revisarei com mais calma sua resposta e do @bigown, pois são definições que se deve entender bem, para utiliza-las nas situações adequadas. +1

Comment: Aproveite e leia sobre algumas motivações por trás de checked e unchecked exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html