# É correto programarmos retornando exceções ao acontecer algo esperado?

Tags: java, exceção, estilo-de-codificação

Quando estamos desenvolvendo um software podemos passar por situações onde acontece algo que não estamos esperando e geralmente quando acontece em muitas linguagens de programação podemos tratar isso dentro de exceções os famosos blocos de código `try/catch`.

Digamos que temos uma classe `Conta`.

```
class ContaCorrente extends Conta {

    public void deposita(double valor) {
        super.saldo += (valor);
    }

    public void saca(double valor) {
        if (super.saldo < valor) {
            throw new SaldoInsuficienteException(
                    "O saldo não é suficiente para saque, Saldo atual é: " + super.saldo + " Você tentou sacar " + valor);
        }
        super.saldo += (valor - 0.10);
    }

}
```

E nesse caso eu criei uma exceção *unchecked* do Java:

```
public class SaldoInsuficienteException extends RuntimeException{
    
    public SaldoInsuficienteException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Para testar criei um simples `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conta conta = new ContaCorrente();
        conta.deposita(200);
        
        try {
            conta.saca(300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

O que retornar? É a gosto do freguês ou tem uma melhor forma?

Comment: Acho que sou meio prático e por isso em alguns casos de abstração tenho dificuldade, eu vejo exceção como uma exceção, se você tem como tratar o fluxo com validações simples como IFs e Switchs então é algo previsto e não exceção... eu trato como exceção algo que não está sob meu controle total, uma conexão com uma API externa por exemplo, no seu exemplo a falta de saldo é previsível então não é uma exceção, mas vejo muitos programadores usando exceção pra isso aí, talvez por não lembrar como é simples um MessageBox ou equivalente.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Polêmica

Isso gera um pouco de polêmica porque há quem defenda uma coisa e outros que acham o oposto. Ninguém provou qual é o certo, então todo mundo só tem opiniões. Alguns fundamentam mais que outros. Dependendo de quem lê e do conhecimento prévio de cada um, quem lê vai acreditar em uma coisa ou outra. Eu mesmo já falei disto em diversas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)
- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)
- [Boas práticas com tratamento de exceção Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186617/101)
- [Exception vs RuntimeException, quando utilizar um ou outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55624/101)
- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)
- [O que são checked exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214768/101)
- [Usando as palavras-chave Throws e Throw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101)

Basicamente a pergunta já foi respondida.

O resumo de tudo isso é que tem uma escola que diz que exceção é a solução para tudo que não era bem o que você queria, ou em outras palavras "exceção cura câncer" e você deve fazer exatamente o que fez. De fato em Java há uma tendência de fazer isso, a API toda adota isso.

## Java se modernizou

Porém mais recentemente Java parou de ser tão dogmática, de ficar repetindo o mantra de que a linguagem é orientada a objeto, e para o bem de todos evoluiu adotando um estilo mais funcional. Acho fantástico que boa parte da comunidade passou adotar esse estilo. E ele prega menos o uso de exceções. Por exemplo criaram o [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) para usar um código de erro em vez de lançar uma exceção quando o erro é esperado.

Então código Java moderno não faria o que foi feito e adotaria um [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) que poderia ser melhor que uma exceção checada. Você informa a inadequação do que se tentou fazer de forma sem fazer uma bagunça no código, sem um peso enorme da exceção.

Java começou adotar a escola que prega que exceções não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo, que elas só devem ser lançadas quando aconteceu algo que não deveria acontecer, ou seja, erros de programação (que não devem ser tratadas), e falhas de ambiente.

O seu código é o jeito antigo de fazer algo porque é esperado que não tenha saldo em algumas situações, não é um erro que o programador cometeu e não é algo que o ambiente causou, é uma regra de negócio esperada, não é excepcional.

## Seu caso

Parabéns por ter criado uma exceção específica para isso, em geral as pessoas não criam. Mas ainda tem um outro erro que quase todos cometem. Ele basicamente usa a mesma estrutura de `Exception` e manda uma mensagem, que pode não ser o adequado para uso em determinada situação.

O mais correto quando cria-se uma exceção nova é tentar fazer algo que só ela tem. A exceção já indica qual foi o problema e em cada contexto que capturar pode ser que a mensagem seja outra. Talvez o mais adequado seja só agregar o saldo (não como mensagem, ter um campo para isso) na exceção para que o consumidor da exceção o use em uma mensagem personalizada. Mas não estou dizendo que está errado, depende do requisito, pode ser que nem o saldo deveria colocar, por segurança e privacidade. Talvez o valor do saque seja o caso de ser incluído.

Veja mais em [Criar exceções personalizadas mais específicas ou mais genéricas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/435767/101).

Mas tem outro problema. Na hora de capturar a exceção pegou a mais genérica possível e isso não faz sentido. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque já respondi em: [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). Se der um erro de memória está fazendo algo que nem imagina.

Eu não gosto de exceções checadas, na forma como o Java implementou, em sistemas complexos muita coisa errada pode acontecer, mas se vai seguir essa escola de abuso das exceções, então sua exceção deveria ser checada já que você não pode ignorar a indicação de falha (pelo menos essa é minha interpretação para o problema).

E isso dá um indício que exceção é um mecanismo difícil de usar. Quase todo mundo que posta algo aqui está cometendo erros com ela e em geral cometem o mesmo erro sempre.

Há quem diga que seu código está perfeito (raro), há quem diga que só errou em capturar `Exception` em vez de `SaldoInsuficienteException`, e também há os que dirão que também errou em fazer a exceção não checada, e finalmente os que dirão que nem deveria ter usado exceção.

Na minha escola, que é seguida por alguns dos melhores programadores do mundo, não ter saldo não é uma falha, é uma situação esperada que acontece e faz parte da regra de negócio, e hoje Java tem o jeito certo de tratar isso.

## Solução alternativa

Eu não costumo usar Java e principalmente os recursos novos não tenho domínio, mas seria mais ou menos isto:

```
import java.util.*;

class Conta {
    public double saldo;
}

class ContaCorrente extends Conta {
    public void deposita(double valor) {
        super.saldo += (valor);
    }
    public Optional<Double> saca(double valor) {
        if (super.saldo < valor) return Optional.empty();
        super.saldo += (valor - 0.10);
        return Optional.of(valor);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente();
        conta.deposita(200);
        var sacado = conta.saca(300);
        if (sacado.isEmpty()) System.out.println("O saldo nao eh suficiente para saque");
        else System.out.println("A operação foi concluída e foi sacado " + sacado.get());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UaG6ub). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/izrccisr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Optional.java).

Dá para fazer de forma mais funcional ainda, eu acho até bom não mudar demais o jeito que aprendeu. Não tome como o código perfeito, esta implementação pode ser melhorada.

Pode ser que o requisito indique que pode sacar o saldo disponível em vez de negar o saque todo. Isso funciona com esse mecanismo, com exceção tem como, mas fica esquisito porque terá dado exceção, mas deu certo e teria que transportar o valor que **deu certo** dentro da exceção. Mesmo que não precise fazer isso nesse caso, em outro pode precisar. Usando o mecanismo certo fica consistente.

Mas eu tenho minhas dúvidas se deve fazer assim. Talvez seja só uma questão de retornar verdadeiro ou falso se a operação não deu certo, e isso Java sempre teve, ficaria algo assim:

```
import java.util.*;

class Conta {
    public double saldo;
}

class ContaCorrente extends Conta {
    public void deposita(double valor) {
        super.saldo += (valor);
    }
    public boolean saca(double valor) {
        if (super.saldo < valor) return false;
        super.saldo += (valor - 0.10);
        return true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente();
        conta.deposita(200);
        if (!conta.saca(300)) System.out.println("O saldo nao eh suficiente para saque");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oSGEqN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hxfhwnhi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Boolean.java).

Atenção que ainda há [outro erro no código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). E tem outros erros conceituais nele.

Comment: Muito bom! muito boa explicação. obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Exceções servem para sinalizar que alguma coisa falhou.

Exceções verificadas (*checked*), ou seja, `Exception` e suas subclasses que não são `RuntimeException`, servem para sinalizar coisas que **devem** ser devidamente tratadas, de forma que esquecer de tratá-las **deve** ser considerado um erro de programação.

Já exceções não-verificadas (*unchecked*), ou seja, `RuntimeException` e suas subclasses, servem para sinalizar coisas que por si só são erros de programação que se manifestaram em tempo de execução, de forma que tentar tratá-las deveria ser inócuo.

Aqui há uma diferença importante. A `RuntimeException` sinaliza um erro de programação que ocorreu, enquanto que as demais `Exception`s sinalizam situações que não são erros de programação, mas que tornar-se-iam em erros de programação se não forem tratadas.

Há ainda os `Error`s, que sinalizam problemas graves, inesperados, imprevisíveis e provavelmente intratáveis. Raramente são tratados porque raramente há algo que possa ser feito para tratá-los.

Você tem então um método para fazer uma determinada coisa, que é sacar dinheiro de uma conta.

- Esse método pode falhar? Pode sim!
- Como ele pode falhar? Se não houver saldo suficiente na conta.
- Esse caso tem que ser tratado? Com certeza!
- E se não for tratado? Deixar de tratar esse caso é um erro de programação!

Logo, isso daí é o caso de criar-se uma exceção verificada (*checked*).

Ou seja, o que você fez está mais ou menos no caminho certo, mas ainda tem alguns erros. O primeiro é que você tem que fazer isso:

```java
public class SaldoInsuficienteException extends Exception {

    public SaldoInsuficienteException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Ou seja, herde de `Exception`, não de `RuntimeException`. A exceção é *checked*, não *unchecked*.

Depois, capturar `Exception` de forma genérica é uma má prática de programação. A boa prática é capturar e tratar exceções específicas, e não exceções genéricas:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conta conta = new ContaCorrente();
    conta.deposita(200);
        
    try {
        conta.saca(300);
    } catch (SaldoInsuficienteException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Além disso, uma vez que exceções verificadas **devem** ser tratadas, logo elas **devem** ser declaradas na cláusula `throws`:

```java
class ContaCorrente extends Conta {

    public void deposita(double valor) {
        super.saldo += (valor);
    }

    public void saca(double valor) throws SaldoInfuficienteException {
        if (super.saldo < valor) {
            throw new SaldoInsuficienteException(
                    "O saldo não é suficiente para saque, Saldo atual é: "
                    + super.saldo + " Você tentou sacar " + valor);
        }
        super.saldo += (valor - 0.10);
    }

}
```

Muita gente tem um certo receio e se frustra em usar exceções verificadas, e frequentemente se referem a elas como um experimento mal-sucedido. No entanto, o que ocorre é que muitas delas são e foram utilizadas incorretamente desde os primórdios do Java, mesmo dentro da JDK, havendo várias situações onde exceções que deveriam ser verificadas foram representadas por `RuntimeException`s e várias situações que não deveriam ser verificadas que foram representadas por `Exception`s forçando o uso de cláusulas `catch` inócuas e irritantes para situações que nunca ocorrem. Outro problema é que as cláusulas `throws` não se dão muito bem com sobreescrita de métodos e nem com lambdas. Além disso, a má prática de programação de usar-se `throws Exception` ou `catch (Exception ex)` também faz com que as vantagens de existirem exceções verificadas sejam perdidas. No entanto, sabendo-se utilizar o conceito de exceções verificadas e não-verificadas de forma correta e com disciplina, o valor de ter exceções verificadas surge em não deixar que situações excepcionais, porém importantes e plausíveis, sejam esquecidas de ser tratadas.

Comment: Bela explicação! muito obrigado.