# O que são Suppressed Exceptions?

Tags: java, exceção

Estou trabalhando em um código onde um método faz várias requisições em uma API iterando em um *loop*. No fim do loop, caso alguma requisição tenha tido um erro, preciso que ele lance uma `Exception` para que eu possa monitorar quais requisições falharam.

Meu código é mais ou menos assim:

```
public class AggregateException extends Exception {


        public void addException(Exception ex){

        addSuppressed(ex);
    }
}


public class AnyClass{

    public AggregateException aggExcep = new AggregateException();

    public void whereExceptionOccurs(){
        try{

              //some code
        }catch(Exception e){

              aggExcep.addException(e);
              //throw aggExcep;
        }  
    }
}
```

Este foi o *output*:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: O SKU '% value%' já está sendo usado por outro produto. 0 
        at br.com.dafiti.service.FeedApi.feedStatus(FeedApi.java:63)
        at br.com.sheup.service.CriarNovoProdutoUseCase.executar(CriarNovoProdutoUseCase.java:42)
        ... 2 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: O SKU '% value%' já está sendo usado por outro produto. 0 Field 'Color' with value 'lilas' does not appear to be a valid option. 1 
        at br.com.dafiti.service.FeedApi.feedStatus(FeedApi.java:63)
        at br.com.sheup.service.CriarNovoProdutoUseCase.executar(CriarNovoProdutoUseCase.java:55)
        ... 2 more Funcionou como esperado, mas não consegui entender o conceito de `Suppressed`.
```

Depois de fazer uma pesquisa, meu entendimento foi que um método só é capaz de lançar uma  única `Exception` durante a execução, sendo assim uma `Suppressed Exception` é uma exceção que quando lançada, será ignorada pelo compilador. Esse entendimento está correto?

Gostaria de uma explicação um pouco mais detalhada ou talvez algum exemplo que se encaixe no meu cenário.

Comment: Está com cara de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/357). Se você quer coletar a informação de quais chamadas a método causaram exceção, colete isso numa lista, `Map` ou de outra forma. Coletar usando o mecanismo de `excecao1.addException(excecao2)` irá disparar esse comportamento de reportar na saída-padrão exceção _suppressed_ / suprimida (isto é, coletada mas ignorada pelo mecanismo de tratameto de exceção do seu programa - não compilador, pois não está em tempo de compilação e sim de execução).

Comment: Obrigado Piovezan pela explicação. Eu acabei utilizando uma lista mesmo, pois presumi que seria mais simples.  Bem interessante essa questão do problema XY

Comment: Se está falando de *suppressed exception* em um bloco *try-with-resources* (que até onde sei, é o único lugar onde a documentação oficial menciona este termo), então já tem uma explicação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confesso que nunca tinha visto o termo, até por não ser um programador de Java. Fui pesquisar e achei a [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) que fala sobre. Também em outros lugares é falado apenas quando usa o `try` *with resources*. Portanto nesse código não faço ideia, a não ser que o código real não seja o apresentado. Na verdade o código nem demonstra como a exceção é lançada.

O que eu consigo ver é que o código é um dos maiores ofensores de uso de exceção que eu já vi, falhando em quase todos os quesitos, ainda que pregado por algumas pessoas. Pode ser visto em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101, [É correto programarmos retornando exceções ao acontecer algo esperado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/483290/101), [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101) e [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101) entre outras. Então pense bem se deseja fazer tudo isto, não parece uma boa idea, o melhor é resolver o problema real.

Tem algo em seu código que você não sabe o que é? E por que o usa então? Nunca use algo sem dominar o que ele faz.

Se ainda quiser insistir nisso, se quer ignorar a exceção e continuar executando o código para depois ver o que fazer, aí ok, eu acho que é o mecanismo errado, mas o prejuízo será só seu.

O mecanismo foi criado justamente para os casos que mais de um erro ocorre e não quer tratar de imediato, em geral, e pra isso foi criado, porque uma exceção está ligada à outra, se não está não deveria ser usada.

Eu percebi que está querendo e vi outras pessoas usarem como um mecanismo de agregação em que acumula diversos erros (que não deveriam ser exceções) em um bloco único. Pode ser feito, claro, o mecanismo deixa. Você terá que usar o `getSuppressed()` para obter essa lista quando resolver tratá-las, o que não foi feito no código, pelo menos que podemos ver, só por isso viu estourar as exceções.

Então para todos os efeitos o que importa é a exceção ser colocada em uma lista e não ser tratada como normalmente acontece.

Então seu entendimento está parcialmente correto. Só que é preciso entender como as coisas funcionam de verdade.

A exceção é um enorme `goto`, sabe [o mecanismo que as pessoas gostam de bater](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101)? Só que bem pior porque você não sabe onde vai parar, ao contrário do `goto` que é sempre logo ali algumas linhas de diferença dentro da própria função.

Então quando você lança uma exceção o código vai parar em algum `catch´ que você não sabe onde é. Neste momento é considerado que você tratou a exceção, não importa o que você faça ali. Pode até relançar a mesma exceção, pode lançar outra exceção, mas não existem duas exceções em funcionamento ao mesmo tempo, só pode lançar outra exceção quando a anterior já foi encerrada. Você pode ir no supermercado e na escola ao mesmo tempo?

Se tiver duas pessoas aí pode, cada uma vai para um lugar. Ver mais em [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). E este é um motivo legítimo para usar o mecanismo. Código paralelo é extremamente complicado de lidar quando sai do básico.

Então a ideia de supressão é justamente guardar a exceção que você deveria ter tratado e não tratou.

A parte interessante é que você poderia fazer isto com um mecanismo próprio. Feito com um mecanismo do *runtime*, ele tem conhecimento e pode usar como desejar a informação armazenada. Se é o que deseja, ótimo (sem entrar no mérito do conceito todo estar errado, pelo menos para um grupo de programadores), se não é, é o mecanismo errado. Quando deixa estourar exceção o *runtime* vai usar de alguma forma, por exemplo exibindo na tela a lista que ele tem de exceções que você oficializou como suprimidas.

Você só consegue se livrar delas tratando de alguma forma a exceção existente. Até mesmo pode engolí-la, o que não é recomendável, mas pode ter algum caso para usar, provavelmente porque todo desenho da aplicação esteja errado.

A exceção suprimida não é uma exceção lançada assim, ela é uma exceção normal que foi suprimida, pelo seu código, você decidiu não tratá-la, mas guardá-la.

Na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) diz que as exceções devem ser irmãs, e não que deve usar para produzir um lista de exceções. Não deixa muito claro as consequências, mas não importa já está sendo usado para o motivo errado.

Eu só quis falar sobre o que é a pergunta título. No seu cenário eu não usaria exceções, até onde eu o entendi.